# Symfony2 "PluginBundle"

Tags: php, symfony, plugins

currently I'm thinking on how to implement a plugin-feature for my symfony2 application.

My goals are as following:

- Basically the plugin should be a bundle (at least service, event listener, routing, entities, migrations, views and controllers need to be registerable)
- The AppKernel should not be touched in any way by the end user or the application
- Plugins should provide meta information (title, description, screenshot/image, author etc)
- plugins should be managed from the backend (activation, deactivation, installation, deletion, update etc)
- plugins may come from different sources (Core, Community, Local as in shopware maybe) and should be seperated by save path
- working autoload without running composer again

My problem would be something like: How to load a bundle after the Kernel is already loaded (since the information on which plugins are active should reside inside the database ideally and not inside some file on the hard disk but may be cached).
I did not found a bundle or a cook book entry on this topic. Is there a best practice managing something like this? Maybe I'm thinking in the wrong direction.

I hope there is someone who might have a helpful idea and the kind of knowledge on symfony2 which I do not have.

PS: There is no code yet since this is just some thinking on the concept on how to handle this.

Comment: About your second bullet point, you can take a look at this article about OroCRM and their method for adding bundles without editing AppKernel : http://oro-quickies.alanstorm.com/no-more-editing-appkernel-to-enable-bundles/

Answer (score 0):

The `AppKernel` returns the registered bundles as an array, so assuming that the storage method you're using to determine active plugins isn't tied to Symfony (i.e. you can access it before the application is fully bootstrapped), then it should be as easy as adding something like this to your `AppKernel.php`:

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    ...
    ...
    $bundles = array_merge($bundles, MyApp\PluginManager::getPluginBundles());
    ...
    return $bundles;
}
```

Providing the plugin metadata could be done in various ways (maybe just a defined location / directory in the plugin files that holds txt / image files), but loading all that should be easy once you have the plugin management stuff (and can easily get the installed plugins, etc) done.

Comment: Hello, metadata prodiding should be quiet easy yes. I just placed it for completeness. The storage engine would be the one configured in symfony (Doctrine ORM) so I think it won't be available before the application is at least partly bootstrapped